# Save and load audio

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

**Unity**

When I click button "Record":
**- Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 10, 44100);**
When I click button "Pause":
**- SavWav.Save (Application.persistentDataPath + "/Resources/storyrecord",aud.clip);**

A files was saved with path : **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.owos.woftbattle/files/Resources/storyrecord**

**com.owos.woftbattle** is my package.
**storyrecord** is my file name.

So, can I open this with code?
This is my code : **Resources.Load("file:///Resources/storyrecord");**

It's not working.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that you cannot write or save to the `Resources` folder in a build(Android). The `Resources` folder can only be created from the Editor. Whatever you put inside the `Resources` folder will be the only thing there. You cannot be able to remove or add more files to the Resources folder. It's read-only once you build your app.

Secondly, saving your file as `Application.persistentDataPath + "/Resources/storyrecord"` will not work. Even if the file saved, that saved file is not in the `Resources` folder. Because it is not, `Resources.Load` cannot read it. *The `Resources.Load` function can only read files that were added to it in the Resources folder from the Editor.*

It's is important that you understand everything above for future reference and to avoid similar mistakes. If you want to save file during run-time, always save your data at: `Application.persistentDataPath/YourFolderName` then load it with the `WWW` class or one of the File API from `System.IO` namespace. The [library](https://gist.github.com/darktable/2317063) you are using is saving it as *".wav"* extension so you must use `WWW` API to load it.

Path to save Audio(Audio Path):

```
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Audio");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, "storyrecord.wav");
```

Save Audio:

```
SavWav.Save (tempPath ,aud.clip);
```

Load Audio as AudioClip:

```
IEnumerator loadAudio(string path)
{
    //Load Audio
    WWW audioLoader = new WWW(path);
    yield return audioLoader;

    //Convert it to AudioClip
    AudioClip aClip = audioLoader.GetAudioClip(false, false, AudioType.WAV);
}
```

Loading it requires a coroutine function so you must use the StartCoroutine function: `StartCoroutine(loadAudio(tempPath));`

**Note**:

On some Android devices, you must add `"file://"` before you can load the audio with the `WWW` class. 
If that's the case, simply add `path = "file://" + path;` to the first line of code in the `loadAudio` function above to fix the path.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was too busy with several different projects. Thank you so much it worked :) . You saved my life !